# Can I migrate some questions from Physics SE to here that are in scope?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, scope

Is it ok to take my early questions, sharpen them up and repost them here?

1 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281828/if-earth-had-rings

2 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225693/using-a-naked-black-hole-as-a-mirror/225697#225697

3 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297890/rainbow-blackhole

4 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/283322/why-is-venus-cloud-covered-but-not-in-an-ice-age

5 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297729/can-a-photon-that-is-emitted-from-a-denser-part-of-the-universe-to-a-less-dense

6 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226458/do-magnetic-fields-exist-beyond-the-gravity-of-a-black-hole

7 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226917/with-gravitational-lensing-could-we-see-our-selves-from-a-right-angle

8 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232862/gases-expanding-and-bonding-in-the-vacuum-frozen-clouds

9 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298346/are-most-galaxies-expanding-from-us-as-previously-calculated

10 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/269934/extinction-level-meteor-effects-on-earths-crust-pending-on-the-surface-area-upo

11 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227738/time-dilation-equals-red-shift-looking-in-or-blue-shift-looking-out

12 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225680/what-is-this-black-hole-merger-orbital-speed

13 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225673/see-behind-the-black-hole

14 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232759/until-when-travel-the-particles-after-the-big-bang-with-light-speed

15 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229629/black-hole-matter-to-subatomic-exchange

16 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231561/super-massive-black-hole-and-photon-reduction

17 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243863/spacetime-mercury-vs-earth

18 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228379/does-the-size-of-a-naked-black-hole-make-a-diffrence-in-photon-sphere-proximity

19 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271148/black-hole-and-critical-mass

20 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231564/can-the-outer-most-layer-of-a-black-hole-be-composed-of-magnetically-trapped-pho

21 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234352/o-energy-asolute-0-matter-at-the-end-of-a-black-holes-acceleration-disk

Fell free to list the one that make a good fit or the bad ones that can't be helped. Some of the questions could be spit into 2 questions.

Comment: Repost, no. Put the links here, and if we accept, you can flag for migration on Physics.

Comment: @called2voyage Can you migrate them?

Comment: No, I'm not a mod on Physics. The Physics mods have to migrate.

Comment: @called2voyage may I put the link here and you can ok it. I want to work on them before they get moved. I cannot improve  them there.

Comment: I can ok receiving them, but you'll still need to get the Physics mods to migrate. If I do give the ok to receive them, then you can link here when you flag for migration and they should be ok with migrating them.

Comment: I can remove invalid answers if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Should stay on Physics

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281828/if-earth-had-rings (Well accepted there, no need to migrate)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225693/using-a-naked-black-hole-as-a-mirror (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297890/rainbow-blackhole (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/283322/why-is-venus-cloud-covered-but-not-in-an-ice-age (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297729/can-a-photon-that-is-emitted-from-a-denser-part-of-the-universe-to-a-less-dense (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226458/do-magnetic-fields-exist-beyond-the-gravity-of-a-black-hole (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226917/with-gravitational-lensing-could-we-see-our-selves-from-a-right-angle (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232862/gases-expanding-and-bonding-in-the-vacuum-frozen-clouds (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298346/are-most-galaxies-expanding-from-us-as-previously-calculated (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/269934/extinction-level-meteor-effects-on-earths-crust-pending-on-the-surface-area-upo (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227738/time-dilation-equals-red-shift-looking-in-or-blue-shift-looking-out (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225673/see-behind-the-black-hole (Same)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229629/black-hole-matter-to-subatomic-exchange (Answered though not well accepted, but not a net negative score, too old to migrate)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243863/spacetime-mercury-vs-earth (Same)

### Too old to migrate, but can be reasked here

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225680/what-is-this-black-hole-merger-orbital-speed
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231561/super-massive-black-hole-and-photon-reduction (It does have a couple answers, but I don't think it would hurt to reask with a clearer question)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228379/does-the-size-of-a-naked-black-hole-make-a-diffrence-in-photon-sphere-proximity
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231564/can-the-outer-most-layer-of-a-black-hole-be-composed-of-magnetically-trapped-pho (Needs to be substantially revised)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234352/o-energy-asolute-0-matter-at-the-end-of-a-black-holes-acceleration-disk (Needs to be substantially revised)

### Unsalvageable

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232759/until-when-travel-the-particles-after-the-big-bang-with-light-speed (look up other questions about the Big Bang here)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271148/black-hole-and-critical-mass

Comment: I would also like to move my well received ones here to if they are more appropriate here?

Comment: @Muze Sorry, that's not how Stack Exchange works. If a question is on topic on it's original site (even if it is arguably "more" on topic elsewhere), we don't move it unless it is poorly received. Doing so would detract from the knowledge base that these sites are trying to build.

Comment: I re asked the first one on the list you gave me. Do I need to space them out time wise? Thanks

Comment: @Muze Just because it didn't get caught does not make it right. Those are considered cross-posts and are generally frowned upon.

Comment: If I had asked them in the right SE and took more time in details they would have done better. Some of them got completely different responses but had tags that would made a good question in 2 or more SE at a time but bad in others.

Comment: @Muze Just looked at the way you asked that here on Astro. It is actually a different question, though it has the same title. That kind of thing is fine.

Comment: Again I want to say thank for helping me with this. I will be using this as a guide to fix the ones there now that I'm off suspension on Physics.SE.

Comment: Well I got suspended again for target up voting. As you know I do up vote to lower voted questions and editing my questions.  Space SE if this is a problem can you let me know and I'll change the way I vote? I don't discriminate or favor anyone here or there.